# How can I keep the working directory of the invoker (outer) batch file, for the invoked (nested/inner) batch file?

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, cmder, elevation

**Let me explain what did I mean.**

I run [cmder.exe](http://cmder.net/) (via `init.bat`) inside a cmd.exe console window. See the attached GIF. For this purpose I wrote a little batch script `cmr.bat` shown below. It does work as it meant to.

```batch
@echo off
%comspec% /k "C:\cmder\vendor\init.bat %*"
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

[image]

But, this approach doesn't provide the ability to run the `init.bat` in **elevated mode** directly.

Being inspired by the [given solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29026783/5259296), I created another batch file `amr.bat` in order to run the inner `init.bat` in **elevated mode**.

Here is the content of the `amr.bat`

```batch
:: Automatically check & get admin rights V2
@echo off
:: BatchGotAdmin
::-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"="
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: START OF USER CUSTOM CODE
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

%comspec% /k "C:\cmder\vendor\init.bat %*" rem THIS IS MY CODE
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

---

The `amr.bat` does run the `init.bat` in the **elevated mode**, but **doesn't keep (retain) the working directory from which it has been called**. The below GIF screencast demonstrates this behavior.

[image]

The `init.bat` **didn't receive the working directory from which it was invoked**. Instead `init.bat` was started with the **working directory set to the location of** the `amr.bat` (which resides in `C:\BatScripts` directory).

---

So my question is, **how can I modify** the `amr.bat` script, **in order to keep (retain) the current directory from which it was invoked**?

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution wasn't obvious for me, however it was much simpler than I expected it to be.**

Being driven by [this hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45624783/5259296), I've realized that the **current context** (working directory of the invoker batch file) **had to be captured** and passed to the VBScript file.

I've modified my `amr.bat` script in the following way.

```batch
@echo off

:: Let me capture the current working directory
set InvokerCapturedWorkingDirectory=%cd%

:: BatchGotAdmin
::-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"="
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%comspec%", "/k C:\cmder\vendor\init.bat %params% & cd /d %InvokerCapturedWorkingDirectory%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: START OF USER CUSTOM CODE ::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: IS NOT NEEDED ANYMORE
::%comspec% /k "C:\cmder\vendor\init.bat %*"
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

---

Let me **confirm** my words:

[image]

---

If you are curious about the **content** of the **generated** VBScript file (**which runs the batch file in elevated mode**), here you are:

[image]